# Form not using the file in action attribute

Tags: php, forms, easyphp

I have a very simple HTML form that is supposed to send information to the file written in action attribute via GET but somehow it's transfering the information back to index.php:

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>PHP Forms Sandbox</h1>

<form acton="process_form.php" method="get">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**process_form.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>PHP Response Sandbox</h1>

<?php

$username = $_GET["username"];
$email = $_GET["email"];

echo $username . " : " . $email . "<br />";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The bizarre aspect is that when I submit the form, the URL shows that it is not even using process_form.php:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Learning/?username=test&email=x%40test.com&submit_btn=Submit
```

If I manually change the URL to include process_form.php it seems to be working fine and I get the results I am looking for:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Learning/process_form.php?username=test&email=x%40test.com&submit_btn=Submit
```

On my development computer, I'm running EasyPHP 14.1 local WAMP server and thought it might be the root of the problem so I uploaded the files to my website that is running newest PHP on Apache, but the problem still exists there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo error in `action`; you have given ***acton***. Should be like this:

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="get">
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Was thinking the same thing. +1

Comment: Amazing! I was looking that line for an hour and didn't spot it. I think I need to find an IDE with a spell checker, lol.

Answer (score 1):

First thing - you have a typo:

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="get">
         ^
```

The second thing - in my opinion the best method of handling forms is using `POST` method, not `GET`, so I would change it to:

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="post">
```

and in `process_form.php` I would use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: Why -1 ? Someone can tell?

Answer (score 0):

After digging around your question,

Index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>PHP Forms Sandbox</h1>
<form action="process_form.php" method="get">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
<label for="email">E-mail:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

process_form.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body> 
<h1>PHP Response Sandbox</h1>
<?php
$username = $_GET["username"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
echo $username . " : " . $email . "<br />";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: If you will not specify form method, By default it will take GET method. So please make sure action should be perfect.

Above code just copy and paste, it should work perfect.

Ask me for further clarification.

Thanks,
Gauttam